# splitting a file into multiple files with a key word using python

Tags: python, file, split

I have a large text file in python. I want to split it into 2, using a keyword. The file above the keyword must be copied to one file and the rest of the file into other. I want to save these files with different extensions in the same directory. Please help me with this.

Also, how to convert a file from one format to another format? 
For example, .txt to .xml or .cite to .xml ?

Comment: Hi, please edit your question to share any code you have already tried, as well as any research you've done on this that didn't help.

Comment: Google for file management. Also, consider loading whole file as text and using text.split(keyword) - that will split it into 2 strings and you can just save them as different files.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the first part of your question, you can simply use the `split` function after reading the text and write them to your new files:

```
with open('oldfile.txt', 'r') as fh:
    text_split = fh.read().split(keyword)

with open('newfile' + extension1, 'w') as fh:
    fh.write(text_split[0])

with open('newfile' + extension2, 'w') as fh:
    # If you know that the keyword only appears once
    # you can changes this to fh.write(text_split[1])
    fh.write(keyword.join(text_split[1:]))
```

The second part of your question is much more difficult. I don't know what kind of file format that you are working with, but txt files are just plain text with no specific structure. XML files cannot be converted from any arbitrary format. If you are working with XML files with a .txt format, you can simply change the format to XML, but if you are looking to convert a format like CSV, I suggest you use a library such as [lxml](https://lxml.de/).

Edit: If the file does not fit into memory, then you can iterate through the lines instead:

```
with open('oldfile.txt', 'r') as fh:
    fh_new = open('newfile' + extension1, 'w')
    keyword_found = False
    line = fh.readline()
    while line:
        if not keyword_found:
            text_split = line.split(keyword)
            fh_new.write(text_split[0])
            if len(text_split) > 1: 
                fh_new.close()
                keyword_found = True
                fh_new = open('newfile' + extension2, 'w')
                fh_new.write(text_split[1:])
        else:
            fh_new.write(line)

        line = fh.readline()
    fh_new.close()
```

Comment: your solution to split a file is a bad idea for files large enough to not fit into memory all at once. he said he has a large file.

Comment: @kamyarhaqqani if you have any suggestions for efficient solutions, please let me know. That would be really helpful. Thanks man!

Comment: @Bharath kumar k i have posted an answer.

Comment: I’ve updated the answer with a solution if your file won’t fit into memory

Answer (score -1):

about splitting your file this should do it( considering the largeness of the file):

```
import mmap
regex=b'your keyword'
f=open('your_path_to_the_main_file','rb')
s = mmap.mmap(f.fileno(), 0, access=mmap.ACCESS_READ)
first_occurance_position=s.find(regex)
if(first_occurance_position==0)
 print('this is a mistake')
 f.close()
 quit()

buf_size=0xfff
first_part_file=open('your_path_to_the_first_part'+'.its_extension','wb')
second_part_file=open('your_path_to_the_second_part'+'.its_extension','wb')
i=0;
if(buf_size>len(regex)):
 buf_size=len(regex)
b=f.read(buf_size)
while(b):
 i=i+buf_size
 first_part_file.write(b)
 if(i==first_occurance_position):
  break
 if(first_occurance_position-i<buf_size):
  buf_size=first_occurance_position-i
 b=f.read(buf_size)

b=f.read(0xffff)
while(b):
 second_part_file.write(b)
 b=f.read(0xffff)

first_part_file.close()
second_part_file.close()
f.close()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How is it different from copying each line until we get the keyword and then copying the rest into some other file? May I know how it is efficient?

Comment: you didn't ask for an answer more efficient than what you mentioned.